# How to quick start apache drill and perform queries on a csv file?

Tags: apache-drill

I have managed to install apache drill on a ubuntu 14.04 headless virtual machine.

I have placed a csv file I want to perform queries on.

I read the tutorials, but none of it makes sense to me when I just want a quick start.

[image: Got it to install. Now what?]

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

If your CSV has does not have a header line, query the file like this:

```
select * from dfs.`/Users/khahn/drill/apache-drill-1.1.0/csv_no_header.csv`;
+------------------------+
|        columns         |
+------------------------+
| ["hello","1","2","3"]  |
| ["hello","1","2","3"]  |
| ["hello","1","2","3"]  |
| ["hello","1","2","3"]  |
| ["hello","1","2","3"]  |
| ["hello","1","2","3"]  |
| ["hello","1","2","3"]  |
+------------------------+
7 rows selected (1.427 seconds)
```

If your csv does have a header line, you need to add the skipFirstLine attribute to the storage plugin (dfs in this example) definition:

```
"csv": {
  "type": "text",
  "extensions": [
    "csv"
  ],
  "skipFirstLine": true,
  "delimiter": ","
},
```

Updating the storage plugin through REST is described in the [Apache Drill docs](http://apache.github.io/drill/docs/plugin-configuration-basics/#storage-plugin-rest-api).

CSV with header line:

```
name, num1, num2,num3
hello,1,2,3
hello,1,2,3
hello,1,2,3
hello,1,2,3
hello,1,2,3
hello,1,2,3
hello,1,2,3
```

The query for selecting all would be the same as the query for the CSV without the header. The output would also be the same.

To query a single column, [use the COLUMNS[n] syntax](http://apache.github.io/drill/docs/querying-plain-text-files/#columns-n-syntax).

Other storage plugin configuration changes might have to be made, depending on your CSV file contents. See [Configuring Drill to Read Text Files](http://apache.github.io/drill/docs/text-files-csv-tsv-psv/#configuring-drill-to-read-text-files).

Comment: You wrote 2 answers. Could you consolidate into one?